# Вывести всего одну запись

Tags: sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT Клиент.id, Клиент.фио, SUM(Стоимость) AS Сумма
FROM Клиент LEFT JOIN ( 
 SELECT Тур.цена*Заказ.количество AS Стоимость, Заказ.клиент
 FROM Тур INNER JOIN Заказ ON Тур.id = Заказ.тур
) AS ТурЗаказ ON Клиент.id=ТурЗаказ.клиент
GROUP BY Клиент.id, Клиент.фио
ORDER BY Sum(ТурЗаказ.Стоимость) DESC;
```

Требуется вывести самую верхнюю запись, а другие не выводить. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: LIMIT 1 ? Нет?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT **TOP 1** Клиент.id...

Comment: Я наверно не совсем точно описал задачу. Мой запрос выводит записи из базы, сортируя их по максимальной сумме заказа. А мне нужно, чтобы вывелись не все записи, а только запись с максимальной суммой (самая верхняя) и желательно, чтобы это делалось в одном запросе((

Comment: @Григорий Пономарёв, мы Вас прекрасно поняли, правда не совсем понятно, что Вам в наших ответах непонятно...

Answer (score 0):

[Select top](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

Comment: А как это использовать в одном запросе?(

Comment: top поддерживается не во всех диалектах SQL...

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_sql_tips_and_solutions_10.html) есть примеры.